# Javascript is not working with doctype html

Tags: javascript, jquery, doctype

I have this javascript code which works only without `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

This code is used for an infinite scroll pagination.

I tried to trigger an alert when the bottom of the page hits but that also does not work.

What is wrong with this code ?

```js
var ajax_arry=[];
var ajax_index =0;

$(function(){
  $('#loading').show();
  $("#pagination").hide();
  $.ajax({
    url:"/ajax",
    type:"POST",
    data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page_nr+"&view="+filter,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
      $('#loading').hide();
      $('#demoajax').html(response);

    }

  });

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(ajax_arry.length>0){
      $('#loading').hide();
      for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
        ajax_arry[i].abort();
      }
    }
    var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
    var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

    if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
      $('#loading').show();

      $.ajax({
        url:"/ajax",
        type:"POST",
        data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page+"&view="+filter,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
          $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
          $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
          $('#loading').hide();

          $('#demoajax').append(response);

        }

      });
      ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

    }
    return false;

  });

});
```

Other script used in the same page is bootstrap.min

Comment: Please write your question perfectly so other can understand and help you.

Comment: We don't need to be rude.. Can you show us the HTML you are containing it in ? Have you included `<script>` encasing tags, have you included `jQuery` dependancy lib etc, we need to know the basics.

Comment: Can you please post a detailed explanation of what you expect, what the console outputs (errors, ecc...), and something can help others to undestand your question?

Comment: There`s are no errors in console.

Comment: I included jquery.min and my script in the head <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="infinite-scroll.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change if to

```
if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() == $(document).height() && isload=='true'){
```

Comment: Worth adding explanation why the original code is working without the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. (Quirks mode)